# Use Powershell variable in another variable / in parameter of a commandlet

Tags: powershell, variables

I would like to use a variable with variable name in 2 examples

**Example 1:**

```
$Myvalue1 = "$AutomateProcessing"
```

I want to put `$false` in my variable `$AutomateProcessing` using

```
$"$Myvalue1" = $false
```

(in place of `$AutomateProcessing = $false`)

**Example 2:**

```
$Myvalue2 = "AutomateProcessing"

Get-EXOMailbox $MyMBX | set-CalendarProcessing -$Myvalue2 $MyConfig
```

(in place of `Get-EXOMailbox $MyMBX | set-CalendarProcessing -AutomateProcessing $MyConfig`)

With this, I could create a loop with a lot of parameters I want to modifiy.

Is it possible to do with PowerShell?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you rephrase? I am having a hard time understanding what you're after.

Comment: Re example 1: What you're looking for is _variable indirection_, where you refer to a variable _indirectly_, via its name stored in a different variable or provided by an expression. PowerShell enables this via the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlets, but note that there are usually better alternatives. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68213804/45375) for details.

Comment: Re example 2: Use splatting - see [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is not clear.

On the second example you mentioned, You can achieve this if you store the entire commandlet as a string first and use Invoke-Expression to trigger it.

Something like this.

```
[string] $FullCommandlet = "Get-EXOMailbox $MyMBX | set-CalendarProcessing -$Myvalue2 $MyConfig"

Invoke-Expression -Command $FullCommandlet
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be _avoided_ and used only as a _last resort_, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

Comment: Exactly what I searched. simple and efficient! Thank you very much

Comment: Also thank you for the remark about the security risk of such command

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cmdlet [set-variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable?view=powershell-7.2).

Use switch "Variable" to define your variable (without $ sign) and the switch "Value" for the value.

```
$AutomateProcessing=$true
$Myvalue1 = "AutomateProcessing"
Set-Variable -Name $Myvalue1 -Value $false
Out-Host -InputObject "Variable $Myvalue1 is now set to $AutomateProcessing"
```

The result:

```
Variable AutomateProcessing is now set to False
```

Comment: Exactly what I searched. simple and efficient! Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to help.
Don't forget to set an accepted answer.

Comment: The problem is that I can only set one accepted answer... You've the good one for the first example and Shabarinat has the good answer for the second example....

Answer (score 0):

Try Splatting your parameters in from a hashtable

```
Param(
[array]$MyMBX = <array>,
[String]$AddOrganizerToSubject = <value>,
[bool]$AutomateProcessing = <value>,
[bool]$AllowRecurringMeetings = <value>
)
Foreach($mbx in $MyMBX){
$Myconfig = @{'Identity' = (Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $mbx)
             'AutomateProcessing' = $AutomateProcessing 
             'AddOrganizerToSubject' = $AddOrganizerToSubject
             'AllowRecurringMeetings' = $AllowRecurringMeetings
              }# etc etc
Set-CalendarProcessing @Myconfig
}
```

Comment: [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) is a great tip, but your answer would be more helpful if it focused on how to apply it to the OP's second example.

Comment: Thank you for your help.... a little more complex to use with a lot of values but to be investigate. Here in my case, I try to compare each value to a default value and change only if needed. In your explanation, we change all the settings each time.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified to just Automateprocessing

```
Param(
[array]$MyMBX = <array>,
[bool]$AutomateProcessing = $false,
)
Foreach($mbx in $MyMBX){
$Myconfig = @{'Identity' = (Get-EXOMailbox -Identity $mbx)
             'AutomateProcessing' = $AutomateProcessing 
              } 
Set-CalendarProcessing @Myconfig
}
```